# Different ways to set org-roam-node-display-template

Tags: text-properties, org-roam

I would like to understand what the differences is between this two variants about setting the value of `org-roam-node-display-template`.

From [here](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam/issues/1819#issuecomment-907762752):

```
(setq org-roam-node-display-template "${title:*} {tags:10}")
```

From [here](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam/commit/6f5d65abd9e707b3fdb10092a9fef3b739e143dd):

```
(setq org-roam-node-display-template
    (concat "${title:*} "
        (propertize "${tags:10}" 'face 'org-tag)))
```

For example I do not know what `propertize` does here with `face` and `org-tag`. I did `C-h o RET propertize` but didn't understand the help text. I assume I miss some Emacs or Lisp basics here to understand that.

Comment: Note that apparently the first one is missing a `$` in front of the opening brace of the `tags` field.

Comment: The only difference AFAICT (after you fix the missing `$` in the first one) is that in the second case, the `tags` string is "propertized" so presumably it has a different face than the `title` field. Other than that they are equivalent. Is there something that causes you a problem with one or the other of them?